# How can I export the record sets of the view to sql with using SQL Server Management Studio Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, ssms

I'm trying to make an automation to export the record sets of the view.
Currently, it's possible to do it if I do them all manually like below.
I'm using SQL Server Management Studio Express and it's connected to the server via ODBC.

1. Click on **New Query**
2. Open **Query Designer** and add a view(Consider the view name is Movies)
3. Input "**select * from Movies;**"
4. Press **Execute** and wait until it finishes retrieving all the record.
5. Right Click on the record sets of the result and select **Save results as**
6. Export the records as **csv**

In fact, I'd like to export it as sql instead.
Is it possible? and how can I make this process automated?

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use BCP commands, please test following [export SQL data to local file](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-output-to-file-using-sql-server-bcp-command.aspx) script

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
SET @cmd = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM Kodyaz.dbo.tablename" queryout "C:\textfile.csv" -t; -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

In the FROM clause, place the fully qualified name of the database table with dbname, schema and table name
You have the option to set the target file too

You can experience error before running the script successfully
For example, you may need to [enable xp_cmdshell](http://www.kodyaz.com/content/xpcmdshell.aspx) and [grant write permission to SQL Server service user](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/unable-to-open-bcp-host-data-file.aspx) on the file folder

I hope that helps as an alternative to SQL Server Import Export Wizard,

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation:) It seems great solution to do all at once. One more thing I'd like to ask you is, my side is client side so that BCP seems not exist on this. Your solution only works on Server side?

Comment: You can run it by connecting to SQL Server instance from your client. The output folder should be accessible from the server. C drive refers to the local drive on server. I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the SQL Server Import Export Wizard if it is available on your SSMS
If you can use it, follow the steps described at [SQL Server export to Excel](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-import-export-wizard.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It seems SSMS Express has less feature than SSMS so that I cannot follow the process :(